# Map identity value to object after merge statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, mapping

I have a table called People with the following schema:

```
Id           INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
FirstName    NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
LastName     NVARCHAR964) NOT NULL
```

I am using a query like this one to perform inserts and updates in one query:

```
MERGE INTO People AS TARGET
USING ( VALUES
    (@id0, @firstName0, @lastname0),
    (@id1, @firstName1, @lastname1)
    ...
) AS SOURCE ([Id],[FirstName],[LastName])
ON TARGET.[Id] = SOURCE.[Id]
WHEN MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    UPDATE SET
        [FirstName] = SOURCE.[FirstName],
        [LastName] = SOURCE.[LastName]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([FirstName],[LastName])
    VALUES ([FirstName],[LastName])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE
OUTPUT $action, INSERTED.*;
```

My application is structured such that the client calls back to the server to load the existing state of the app. The client then creates/modifies/deletes entities locally and pushes those changes to the server in one bunch.

Here's an example of what my "SaveEntities" code currently looks like:

```
public void SavePeople(IEnumerable<Person> people)
{
    // Returns the query I mentioned above
    var query = GetMergeStatement(people);

    using(var command = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                // how do I tie these records back to
                // the objects in the people collection?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can use the value in the `$action` column to filter down to just INSERTED records. `INSERTED.*` returns all of the columns in TARGET for the inserted record. The problem is I have no way of distinctly linking those results back to the collection of objects passed into this method.

The only solution I could think of was to add a writable GUID column to the table and allow the MERGE statement to specify that value so I could link back to these objects in code using that and assign the ID value from there, but that seems like it defeats the purpose of having an automatic identity column and feels convoluted.

I'm really curious how this can work because I know Entity Framework does something to mitigate this problem (to be clear, I believe I'd have to same problem were I to be using a pure INSERT statement instead of a MERGE). In EF I can add objects to the model and call `Entity.SaveChanges()` and have the entity's ID property auto-update using magic. I guess it's that kind of magic I'm looking to understand more.

Also, I know I could structure my saves to insert one record at a time and cascade the changes appropriately (by returning `SCOPE_IDENTITY` for every insert) but this would be terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things I love about the `MERGE` statement is that the source data is in scope in the `OUTPUT` clause.

```
OUTPUT $action, SOURCE.Id, INSERTED.Id;
```

On insert, this will give you three columns: 'INSERT' in the first, the values of `@id0` and `@id1` in the second, and the matching, newly inserted `Id` values in the third.

In your C# code, just read the rows as you normally would.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    string action = reader.GetString(0);
    if (action == "INSERT")
    {
        int oldId = reader.GetInt32(1);
        int newId = reader.GetInt32(2);

        // Now do what you want with them.
    }
}
```

You can check for "DELETE" and "UPDATE" too, but keep in mind that ordinal 2 will be `NULL` on "DELETE" so you need to make sure you check for that before calling `reader.GetInt32` in that case.

I've used this, in combination with table variables (`OUTPUT SOURCE.Id, INSERTED.Id INTO @PersonMap ([OldId], [NewId])`), to copy hierarchies 4 and 5 tables deep, all with identity columns.

Comment: This worked with a slight tweak for my use case. I generated a `GUID` for each item in `SOURCE` (in code) and passed it into the `MERGE` statement. Then I `OUTPUT`'d that value along with `INSERTED.Id` and am able to map it back to the source element.